# Preserving (and loading) table view scroll position for each data source

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, appkit, nsscrollview

I am trying to replicate Mail.app behaviours in my app. If you have multiple e-mail accounts and select a random e-mail for each account and switch between each account from the sidebar, the app remembers your scroll position and which e-mail you selected and display them accordingly. That is what I want in my app.

I know how to preserve the row selection, that is easy. `tableView.selectedRowIndexes`

My `tableView` has multiple data sources and switches (`tableView.reloadData()`) accordingly from the sidebar.

I am having a major problem with the scroll position. I tried looking into `NSScrollView`, `NSClipView` and `NSTableView`. It seems to me that there are scrolling mechanism for each view.

1. I need to remember the scroll position when the user scroll for each data source
2. I need to load the previous scroll position when the user return to the data source

Also a strange behaviour I noticed is when reloading `tableView` to a different data source, it seems to persistently remember from the previous data source scroll position. Is that normal? I assumed it would reset to the top.

My data sources are arrays which are my `NSViewController` subclass properties.

If it matters, I am using storyboard, my app is targeting Big Sur and I am using Swift.

Comment: `reloadData()` doesn't change the scroll postion, that's normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position to save:

```
preservedPosition = tableView.visibleRect.origin
```

Restore:

```
tableView.scroll(preservedPosition)
```

Comment: I forgot to ask in my original question. How can I save the scroll position without the user selecting the table row?

Comment: @user10711707 The scroll position is not related to the selected row.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as solved because it does get me the table scroll position. Thanks! However, I have some weird "bugs" related to this. I can't tell if it my programming mistakes or something else. I will have to make a separate question about it.